# Can't find Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener sources

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx, coreclr

I'm experimenting with the new **vnext** thingy, and I like that I can find source code of every module in github, since it is opensourced.

For every module except one: **Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener**. I looked through the contents of **aspnet** user repositories but found nothing.

Does anybody know where the source for this class is located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know both WebListener and Helios (discontinued) are both currently closed source, and are held in private repositories.

You could look at [Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer) as it is going to become the defacto server going forward, with WebListener being something that may or may not gain features like HTTP/2 as quickly as Kestrel might.